# Push output of results to an array

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm running the below scrpt to return a resultset of disk capacity from a list of all available servers within our estate. I'd like to append the outputs and combine them into one dataset to make it easy to display and interrogate. I am aware of how to append values to an array with one column however as this would require multiple, I'm not sure how to acheive this. Is it possible to append the result set from this output to an array?

```
$myarray = @("")
$servers =
   @(
         'SERVER1'
        ,'SERVER2'
        ,'SERVER3'
        ,'SERVER4'
        ,'SERVER5'
        ,'SERVER6'

    )
$wmiQuery = @"
SELECT
    SystemName,Name,DriveType,FileSystem,FreeSpace,Capacity,Label
FROM
    Win32_Volume
"@

Foreach ($server in $servers)
{

        Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -Query $wmiQuery| Select-Object @{Name = "Computer"; Expression={$server}},Name,
        Label,
        @{Name = "SizeInGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f ($_.Capacity/1GB)}},
        @{Name = "UsedSizeInGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f (($_.Capacity - $_.FreeSpace)/1GB)}},
        @{Name = "FreeSizeInGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
        @{Name = "FreePerc"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f (($_.FreeSpace/1GB)/($_.Capacity/1GB))}}|Where-Object FreePerc -LE 0.16|Format-Table

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by storing the output of your foreach loop to an array.

```
$servers = @('SERVER1','SERVER2','SERVER3','SERVER4','SERVER5','SERVER6')
$wmiQuery = @"
SELECT
    SystemName,Name,DriveType,FileSystem,FreeSpace,Capacity,Label
FROM
    Win32_Volume
"@
$myarray = Foreach ($server in $servers)
{

    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -Query $wmiQuery |
      Select-Object @{Name = "Computer"; Expression={$server}},Name,Label,
      @{Name = "SizeInGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f ($_.Capacity/1GB)}},
      @{Name = "UsedSizeInGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f (($_.Capacity - $_.FreeSpace)/1GB)}},
      @{Name = "FreeSizeInGB"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f ($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
      @{Name = "FreePerc"; Expression={"{0:N2}"-f (($_.FreeSpace/1GB)/($_.Capacity/1GB))}}|Where-Object FreePerc -LE 0.16

}
$myarray | Format-Table
```

I removed the `Format-Table` from the loop because you should only use the `Format-*` commands when you are showing your final output not when you are going to be using that output for other processing. The `$myarray` variable will be an array with each element being an object with the properties from your `Get-WmiObject` query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of doing this would be by following what is shown in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediaandmicrocode/2008/11/27/microcode-powershell-scripting-tricks-the-joy-of-using-hashtables-with-windows-powershell/) from Microsoft

Basically, you can create a nested hashtable. One hashtable for all the servers and then another nested inside it for the values. This is a little example for you :)

```
$resultsHash = @{
    SERVER1 = @{
        SizeInGB=""
        UsedSizeInGB=""
        FreeSizeInGB=""
        FreePerc=""
    }
    SERVER2 = @{
        SizeInGB=""
        UsedSizeInGB=""
        FreeSizeInGB=""
        FreePerc=""
    }
}
```